# How do I find the projection of $y$ onto $W^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My guess is first to find the basis for W perp which gives me the vector (2,-2,1). I would then find the projection of y onto W perp.

To make it orthonormal, I would have to multiply the vector by one over its magnitude.

To find the distance for W perp would it be the magnitude of y - projection of y onto W perp?

To find the distance from W do i have to find the projection of y onto W first and then find the magnitude of y - projection of y onto W?

Comment: Hint: What’s left when you subtract the projection of $\vec y$ onto $W^\perp$ from $\vec y$?

Comment: the vector orthogonal to w perp

Comment: You might want to consider posting this onto our Piazza page for the course so that other students can be a part of the discussion, too!

Comment: Note, that there is a sign missing in your basis vector for  $W^{\perp}$: $(2,-2,\color{blue}{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost correct with your basis of $W^{\perp}$. If we let $v = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, then $v^Tu_2 = \dots~$?

Since $W^{\perp}$ is one dimensional (why?), you're correct that we can find $\operatorname{proj}_{W^{\perp}}(y)$ by finding $\operatorname{proj}_v(y)$.

You're correct about finding the orthonormal basis -- it is exactly $v/\|v\|$ (once you've corrected $v$).

You're correct that the distance from $y$ to $W^{\perp}$ is $\|y - \operatorname{proj}_v(y)\|$.

And you're correct about finding the distance from $y$ to $W$. Once you can find $\operatorname{proj}_{W}(y)$, then the distance is $\|y - \operatorname{proj}_{W}(y)\|$. How can you find $\operatorname{proj}_{W}(y)$?

Comment: why would we need to multiply by v transpose by u2

Comment: Well, if we want $v$ to be in $W^{\perp}$, and $u_2\in W$, then ...